# change dimensions videos format via ffmpeg-php to a custom size without stretch

Tags: php, ffmpeg

[image]I use this code to convert and change dimensions videos format to each other...

```
exec("ffmpeg  -i $SourcePath -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 1200x800 $uploadpath1 2>&1")
```

But I have a poblem...

for example If the input video dimensions is 600 * 300...output video dimensions will be 1200*600 but without stretch...just with a black background with a 1200*600 video inside it...

If u did not underestand my mean...I attached a pic to this question to explain my mean better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to embedd your small video input in a larger video, you can use the `pad`filter like in the below example where I put a 720x404 video in a 1280x720 video with the top left pixel at (0,72)

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf pad=1280:720:0:72 out.mp4
ffmpeg version N-58949-g0e575c2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec  9 2013 22:06:49 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 58.100 / 52. 58.100
  libavcodec     55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
  libavformat    55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     3. 92.100 /  3. 92.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.22.100
  Duration: 00:05:00.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5250 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 720x404 [SAR 1:1 DAR 180:101], 5020 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 221 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 000000000030f480] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000000000030f480] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 000000000030f480] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 000000000030f480] 264 - core 140 r2377 1ca7bb9 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.22.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvo_aacenc)
```